# Xcode build error - missing required architecture i386

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-construction, ios-simulator, static-libraries

I know this means that a 3rd party component doesn't run on the simulator:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /MyApp/SomeComponent.include/SomeComponent.framework/SomeComponent, missing required architecture i386 in file /MyApp/SomeComponent.include/SomeComponent.framework/SomeComponent (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SomeComponent", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MyViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

But, I don't want to be excluded from ever running the app again on the simulator. The 3rd party component is only required when pushing a button in a certain part of the app. I still want to be able to run the rest of the app in the simulator.

How can I get the compiler to ignore this if I'm running in the simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could conditionally compile the code using that framework:

```
 #if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
 // Code using "SomeComponent" that should be compiled for iOS device only ...
 #endif
```

Alternatively, you could "weakly link" against the framework (as described in
["Using Weakly Linked Classes in iOS"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002000-SW3) and check the availability
of the class at runtime:

```
if ([SomeComponent class]) {
    // Create an instance of the class and use it.
} else {
    // Alternate code path to follow when the
    // class is not available.
}
```

Comment: I like the second alternative better, but I'm forced to use the first since I don't know how I'd use the second with this line: @interface MyViewController () <SomeComponentFinished>